# Maven Error cached in Local Repository error

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My Maven Clean Install is success but my pom.xml still shows compilation error.

The Error is 
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
 not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
 NullPointerException

I have Tried restarting eclipse and Updating the Maven Projects Still the Complation error is not going.

Any Resolution for this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Run maven with enforce an update:

   `mvn -U clean install` or `mvn -U verify`
2. If that doesn't work, delete the artifact from your local maven repo:

   `rm -R ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/`

   and run maven again (`mvn clean install` or `mvn verify`).

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting the artifact from your local maven repository and running the maven build again. It should try downloading the latest updated artifact.
Generally the caching issue happens because of the .lastUpdated file created in your artifact's directory in local repo.